# java compile problem on cmd (json simple)

Tags: java, json, cmd, compiler-errors, reference-library

I'm trying to compile my java program using cmd.
The program works well on the eclipse, but not on the cmd.
The error message was cannot find a symbol under the variable that declared by `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`,...etc(JSON something).

So it seems like cmd can not recognize `json.simple`. I downloaded json simple on my desktop, and I successfully imported it. Also, I set a json-simple file for referenced libraries on the eclipse.

Why cmd can not find the imported json-simple file?
Understanding the file and how it works with the compiler is too hard for me.
Anyone knows good articles, videos, or book to study this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on how you added those libraries, since you have downloaded and manually linked the files to your project what you could do is use the `-classpath` option in the `javac` program something like `javac -classpath PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR` if you can choose next time try using a build tool like maven, gradle or ant, it's a bit more work to configure at the beginning but it makes sure your code can be compiled from the command line